# How to hide JToolTip background when exceeding borders?

Tags: java, swing, tooltip

I've created this custom JToolTip for my application. When the tooltip is entirely diplayed inside a JFrame, no background is visible (expected), but when the tooltip is displayed outside the JFrame, the background will be visible. How can I have it removed either way?

I've tried `setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255, 0));` with the '0' alpha value to make sure the background is transparent, but that didn't do the trick.

The tooltip inside the frame, as expected:

[image: tooltip inside frame]

The tooltip exceeding the JFrame, with the unwanted background:

[image: tooltip exceeding frame]

The custom JTooltip:

```
 public class DefaultToolTip extends JToolTip {

        public DefaultToolTip() {
            setOpaque(false);
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(275, 30));
            setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255, 0));
        }

        @Override
        public void addNotify() {
            super.addNotify();
            setOpaque(false);
            Component parent = this.getParent();
            if (parent != null) {
                if (parent instanceof JComponent) {
                    JComponent jparent = (JComponent) parent;
                    jparent.setOpaque(false);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            String text = getComponent().getToolTipText();

            addNotify();
            Graphics2D g2d = drawComponent(g);
            drawText(text, g2d);

            g2d.dispose();
        }

        private void drawText(String text, Graphics2D g2d) {
            //Draw the text
            int cHeight = getComponent().getHeight();
            FontMetrics fm = g2d.getFontMetrics();
            g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            if (cHeight > getHeight())
                g2d.drawString(text, (getWidth() - fm.stringWidth(text)) / 2, (getHeight() + fm.getAscent()) / 2 + 2);
            else
                g2d.drawString(text, (getWidth() - fm.stringWidth(text)) / 2, (cHeight + fm.getAscent()) / 2 + 2);
        }

        private Graphics2D drawComponent(Graphics g) {
            //Create a round rectangle
            Shape round = new RoundRectangle2D.Float(0, 8, getWidth(), getHeight(), 8, 8);

            //Draw the background
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g2d.setColor(Color.GRAY);
            g2d.fill(round);

            //Draw the left triangle
            Point p1 = new Point(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() - 30);
            Point p2 = new Point(getWidth() / 2 + 8, getHeight() - 20);
            Point p3 = new Point(getWidth() / 2 - 8, getHeight() - 20);
            int[] xs = {p1.x, p2.x, p3.x};
            int[] ys = {p1.y, p2.y, p3.y};
            Polygon triangle = new Polygon(xs, ys, xs.length);
            g2d.fillPolygon(triangle);
            return g2d;
        }
    }
```

### Solution

A few things have changed to have the tooltip behave as expected. the `paint` method has been replaced by the `paintComponent` method, the `addNotify` call was removed, the method updated to fetch the window of the component and to give it a transparent background. `setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());` was also needed to remove the components default border.

```
public class DefaultToolTip extends JToolTip {

    public DefaultToolTip() {
        setOpaque(false);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(275, 30));
        setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255, 0));
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
    }

    @Override
    public void addNotify() {
        super.addNotify();
        setOpaque(false);
        Component parent = this.getParent();
        if (parent != null) {
            if (parent instanceof JComponent) {
                JComponent jparent = (JComponent) parent;
                jparent.setOpaque(false);
            }
        }
        Window window = SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(this);
        try {
            window.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255, 0));
        } catch (IllegalComponentStateException e) {
            //Do nothing
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        //super.paintComponent(g);
        String text = getComponent().getToolTipText();

        Graphics2D g2d = drawComponent(g);
        drawText(text, g2d);

        g2d.dispose();
    }

    private void drawText(String text, Graphics2D g2d) {
        //Draw the text
        int cHeight = getComponent().getHeight();
        FontMetrics fm = g2d.getFontMetrics();
        g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        if (cHeight > getHeight())
            g2d.drawString(text, (getWidth() - fm.stringWidth(text)) / 2, (getHeight() + fm.getAscent()) / 2 + 2);
        else
            g2d.drawString(text, (getWidth() - fm.stringWidth(text)) / 2, (cHeight + fm.getAscent()) / 2 + 2);
    }

    private Graphics2D drawComponent(Graphics g) {
        //Create a round rectangle
        Shape round = new RoundRectangle2D.Float(0, 8, getWidth(), getHeight(), 8, 8);

        //Draw the background
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2d.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        g2d.fill(round);

        //Draw the left triangle
        Point p1 = new Point(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() - 30);
        Point p2 = new Point(getWidth() / 2 + 8, getHeight() - 20);
        Point p3 = new Point(getWidth() / 2 - 8, getHeight() - 20);
        int[] xs = {p1.x, p2.x, p3.x};
        int[] ys = {p1.y, p2.y, p3.y};
        Polygon triangle = new Polygon(xs, ys, xs.length);
        g2d.fillPolygon(triangle);
        return g2d;
    }
}
```

A note however, `super.paintComponent(g)` was commented out, since it would draw text another time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know if any of these will help but:

1. Don't override paint(...). Custom painting is done by overriding `paintComponent(...)`.
2. Invoke super.paintComponent(...) as the first statement
3. Don't invoke `addNotify()` in a painting method. A painting method is for painting only.

> with the '0' alpha value to make sure the background is transparent,

Swing components don't know how to handle transparent backgrounds. Just make the component non-opaque.

When the tooltip overlaps the component. The tooltip is actually added to a JWindow before it is displayed. So in your addNotify() logic, you can search for the window and make it transparent.

Check out:

```
Window window = SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(...);
```

Comment: Thank you for the outstanding answer and feedback! I will add the solution to the answer.